# android second setContentView fired with button and not show listview

Tags: android, listview

When I call a second layout in the same activity  no show listview, only button and scroll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >     
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="488dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="453dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext" />    
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btinicio"
        android:layout_width="153dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/bt1text"
        android:onClick="hagotest"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

event fired with click button

```
     public void hagotest (View v)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.test_view);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         String s = "";
        s += "    Una sola opcion por linea, pasar el dedo sobre el texto para continuar"+"\n";
        tv2.setText(s);
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lw);
        adapter =new ItemAdapter(this,ArrayItem );
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


       llenolista();
        bt1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlimpio);
        bt2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btResultado);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textSize="12dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                />


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="216dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="5.0sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btlimpio"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bt2txt"
            android:onClick="hagolimpieza"
            android:layout_gravity="center|left"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btResultado"
            android:layout_width="171dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bt3txt"
            android:onClick="resultado"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

this is listitems 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
   >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPregunta"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="12dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/tvSiempre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvPregunta"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvPregunta"
        android:onClick="ckCHEck"
        android:tag=""
    />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/tvOcasio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvSiempre"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvPregunta"
        android:onClick="ckCHEck"
        android:tag=""
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/tvNunca"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvOcasio"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10dip"
       android:text=""
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tvPregunta"
        android:onClick="ckCHEck"
        android:tag=""
        />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need when I click the button show this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView()` shouldn't be called more than once. If you want to add different layouts dynamically you should consider using `Fragments`.